# Lost my Stack Overflow account when I trashed my e-mail address

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid

I used to log in to Stack Overflow using my Yahoo ID. Now that I've deleted my e-mail address I can't access my account on Stack Overflow. I am unable to log in through Stack Exchange either. Is there any way to merge my old profile and my new one?

My old profile:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1809253/v-q

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact).

Comment: Whilst this link might answer the... oh, wait; the text without the link *is* still the answer! ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber You could almost say it's... *sunglasses*... a meta hyperlink.

Comment: @Anna Lear♦ Done that already, but as I am unable to log into my old account, I couldn't edit it to show merge keep.

Comment: @VQ Yeah, that's reasonable. If you provide as much detail as possible about your old account (outside of things that are shown publicly), we may be able to help you out either way. :)